# Sort tuples in a list of lists in a sequence

Tags: python, list, sorting, tuples

I have a several large lists of lists of tuples. One of them is:

```
list_one[:20]
>>>

[[('Bacterium', 'Biologically Active Substance'),
  ('Biologically Active Substance', 'Pharmacologic Substance'),
  ('Pharmacologic Substance', 'Immunologic Factor')],
 [('Bacterium', 'Biologically Active Substance'),
  ('Biologically Active Substance', 'Pharmacologic Substance'),
  ('Pharmacologic Substance', 'Organic Chemical')],
 [('Bacterium', 'Biologically Active Substance'),
  ('Biologically Active Substance', 'Pathologic Function'),
  ('Pathologic Function', 'Finding')],
 [('Pharmacologic Substance', 'Immunologic Factor'),
  ('Biologically Active Substance', 'Pharmacologic Substance'),
  ('Chemical', 'Biologically Active Substance')],
 [('Pharmacologic Substance', 'Organic Chemical'),
  ('Biologically Active Substance', 'Pharmacologic Substance'),
  ('Chemical', 'Biologically Active Substance')],
 [('Biologically Active Substance', 'Pathologic Function'),
  ('Pathologic Function', 'Finding'),
  ('Chemical', 'Biologically Active Substance')],
 [('Pharmacologic Substance', 'Immunologic Factor'),
  ('Biologically Active Substance', 'Pharmacologic Substance'),
  ('Gene or Genome', 'Biologically Active Substance')],
 [('Pharmacologic Substance', 'Organic Chemical'),
  ('Biologically Active Substance', 'Pharmacologic Substance'),
  ('Gene or Genome', 'Biologically Active Substance')],
 [('Biologically Active Substance', 'Pathologic Function'),
  ('Pathologic Function', 'Finding'),
  ('Gene or Genome', 'Biologically Active Substance')],
 [('Disease or Syndrome', 'Sign or Symptom'),
  ('Manufactured Object', 'Disease or Syndrome'),
  ('Molecular Biology Research Technique', 'Manufactured Object')],
 [('Disease or Syndrome', 'Patient or Disabled Group'),
  ('Manufactured Object', 'Disease or Syndrome'),
  ('Molecular Biology Research Technique', 'Manufactured Object')],
 [('Disease or Syndrome', 'Age Group'),
  ('Manufactured Object', 'Disease or Syndrome'),
  ('Molecular Biology Research Technique', 'Manufactured Object')],
 [('Disease or Syndrome', 'Finding'),
  ('Manufactured Object', 'Disease or Syndrome'),
  ('Molecular Biology Research Technique', 'Manufactured Object')],
 [('Disease or Syndrome', 'Population Group'),
  ('Manufactured Object', 'Disease or Syndrome'),
  ('Molecular Biology Research Technique', 'Manufactured Object')],
 [('Disease or Syndrome', 'Animal'),
  ('Manufactured Object', 'Disease or Syndrome'),
  ('Molecular Biology Research Technique', 'Manufactured Object')],
 [('Body Part, Organ, or Organ Component', 'Pathologic Function'),
  ('Pathologic Function', 'Finding'),
  ('Nucleic Acid, Nucleoside, or Nucleotide',
   'Body Part, Organ, or Organ Component')],
 [('Pharmacologic Substance', 'Biologically Active Substance'),
  ('Biologically Active Substance', 'Pathologic Function')],
 [('Pharmacologic Substance', 'Immunologic Factor'),
  ('Biologically Active Substance', 'Pharmacologic Substance'),
  ('Tissue', 'Biologically Active Substance')],
 [('Pharmacologic Substance', 'Organic Chemical'),
  ('Biologically Active Substance', 'Pharmacologic Substance'),
  ('Tissue', 'Biologically Active Substance')],
 [('Biologically Active Substance', 'Pathologic Function'),
  ('Pathologic Function', 'Finding'),
  ('Tissue', 'Biologically Active Substance')]]
```

How can I sort each sublist such that the tuples are in sequence (e.g., `[(1,2), (2,3), (3,4)]`)?

For example, the first sublist

```
[('Bacterium', 'Biologically Active Substance'),
  ('Biologically Active Substance', 'Pharmacologic Substance'),
  ('Pharmacologic Substance', 'Immunologic Factor')]
```

has tuples that are in sequence. The last one however:

```
[('Biologically Active Substance', 'Pathologic Function'),
  ('Pathologic Function', 'Finding'),
  ('Tissue', 'Biologically Active Substance')]
```

is not, and should be:

```
[('Tissue', 'Biologically Active Substance'),
('Biologically Active Substance', 'Pathologic Function'),
  ('Pathologic Function', 'Finding')
  ]
```

Note that the length of the sublist vary between lists (i.e., I have 3 tuples in this list, but I may have 2, 5, or any other number). Also, the tuples can be changed to lists if its easier.

Comment: `for sublist in list_one: sublist.sort()`. Bear in mind that in this loop, `sublist` will be reference to the sublist which is an element of `list_one`, not a copy of it.

Comment: @alani am I missing something? Because it didn't sort it in sequence: `list_one[10]` >>> `[['Pharmacologic Substance', 'Organic Chemical'],
 ['Biologically Active Substance', 'Pharmacologic Substance'],
 ['Gene or Genome', 'Biologically Active Substance']]` . `for sublist in list_one: sublist.sort()`. `list_one[10]` >>> `[['Biologically Active Substance', 'Pharmacologic Substance'],
 ['Gene or Genome', 'Biologically Active Substance'],
 ['Pharmacologic Substance', 'Organic Chemical']]`. I tried to convert the tuples to lists to see if it works as well and it didn't as you can see

Answer (score 1):

Interesting question. You could try the following:

```
def sort(tuples):
    connects = dict(tuples)
    steps = []
    start = (connects.keys() - connects.values()).pop()
    while end := connects.get(start, False):
        steps.append((start, end))
        start = end
    return steps

list_one_sorted = [sort(tuples) for tuples in list_one]
```

- Read the tuples (a sublist of `list_one`) into a dictionary, which gives you a natural way to *walk through* the tuples (start with a key, get the corresponding value, then use the value as key, ...).
- Identify the starting point `start`: the only key that is not in the values.
- Now walk through the tuples, starting with `start`, and collect the thereby sorted tuples in a new list.

Result for your `list_one` is:

```
[[('Bacterium', 'Biologically Active Substance'),
  ('Biologically Active Substance', 'Pharmacologic Substance'),
  ('Pharmacologic Substance', 'Immunologic Factor')],
 [('Bacterium', 'Biologically Active Substance'),
  ('Biologically Active Substance', 'Pharmacologic Substance'),
  ('Pharmacologic Substance', 'Organic Chemical')],
 [('Bacterium', 'Biologically Active Substance'),
  ('Biologically Active Substance', 'Pathologic Function'),
  ('Pathologic Function', 'Finding')],
 [('Chemical', 'Biologically Active Substance'),
  ('Biologically Active Substance', 'Pharmacologic Substance'),
  ('Pharmacologic Substance', 'Immunologic Factor')],
 [('Chemical', 'Biologically Active Substance'),
  ('Biologically Active Substance', 'Pharmacologic Substance'),
  ('Pharmacologic Substance', 'Organic Chemical')],
 [('Chemical', 'Biologically Active Substance'),
  ('Biologically Active Substance', 'Pathologic Function'),
  ('Pathologic Function', 'Finding')],
 [('Gene or Genome', 'Biologically Active Substance'),
  ('Biologically Active Substance', 'Pharmacologic Substance'),
  ('Pharmacologic Substance', 'Immunologic Factor')],
 [('Gene or Genome', 'Biologically Active Substance'),
  ('Biologically Active Substance', 'Pharmacologic Substance'),
  ('Pharmacologic Substance', 'Organic Chemical')],
 [('Gene or Genome', 'Biologically Active Substance'),
  ('Biologically Active Substance', 'Pathologic Function'),
  ('Pathologic Function', 'Finding')],
 [('Molecular Biology Research Technique', 'Manufactured Object'),
  ('Manufactured Object', 'Disease or Syndrome'),
  ('Disease or Syndrome', 'Sign or Symptom')],
 [('Molecular Biology Research Technique', 'Manufactured Object'),
  ('Manufactured Object', 'Disease or Syndrome'),
  ('Disease or Syndrome', 'Patient or Disabled Group')],
 [('Molecular Biology Research Technique', 'Manufactured Object'),
  ('Manufactured Object', 'Disease or Syndrome'),
  ('Disease or Syndrome', 'Age Group')],
 [('Molecular Biology Research Technique', 'Manufactured Object'),
  ('Manufactured Object', 'Disease or Syndrome'),
  ('Disease or Syndrome', 'Finding')],
 [('Molecular Biology Research Technique', 'Manufactured Object'),
  ('Manufactured Object', 'Disease or Syndrome'),
  ('Disease or Syndrome', 'Population Group')],
 [('Molecular Biology Research Technique', 'Manufactured Object'),
  ('Manufactured Object', 'Disease or Syndrome'),
  ('Disease or Syndrome', 'Animal')],
 [('Nucleic Acid, Nucleoside, or Nucleotide',
   'Body Part, Organ, or Organ Component'),
  ('Body Part, Organ, or Organ Component', 'Pathologic Function'),
  ('Pathologic Function', 'Finding')],
 [('Pharmacologic Substance', 'Biologically Active Substance'),
  ('Biologically Active Substance', 'Pathologic Function')],
 [('Tissue', 'Biologically Active Substance'),
  ('Biologically Active Substance', 'Pharmacologic Substance'),
  ('Pharmacologic Substance', 'Immunologic Factor')],
 [('Tissue', 'Biologically Active Substance'),
  ('Biologically Active Substance', 'Pharmacologic Substance'),
  ('Pharmacologic Substance', 'Organic Chemical')],
 [('Tissue', 'Biologically Active Substance'),
  ('Biologically Active Substance', 'Pathologic Function'),
  ('Pathologic Function', 'Finding')]]
```